# If $E(Y|X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2)=0$ and $Var(Y|X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2)=C$ for all possible $x_1,x_2$, then what is $E(Y|X_1=x_1)$ and $Var(Y|X_1=x_1)$?

Tags: probability, variance, conditional-expectation

Given random variables $Y,X_1,X_2$, if $E(Y|X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2)=0$ and $Var(Y|X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2)=C$ (where $C$ is a constant) for all possible combinations of $x_1$ and $x_2$, then is $E(Y|X_1=x_1) = 0$ and $Var(Y|X_1=x_1) = C$? Intuitively I think this could be true but if it is correct, I'm not sure how to show this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Tower property [Conditional_expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation) since
$\sigma(X_1)\subset \sigma(X_1,X_2) $ so

$E(Y|X_1)=E(E(Y|(X_1,X_2))|X_1)$

$E(Y|X_1)=E(E(Y|X_1,X_2)|X_1) = E(0|X_1)=0$

$Var(Y|X_1) =E(Y^2|X_1)-E^2(Y|X_1)= E(Y^2|X_1)$

$=E(E(Y^2|X_1,X_2)|X_1)=E(Var(Y|X_1,X_2)|X_1)
+E(E^2(Y|X_1,X_2)|X_1)=E(C|X_1)+0=C$

Comment: $E[E[Y|X_1,X_2]]$ is constant, but $E[Y|X_1]$ is a function of $X_1$ in general. So the two cannot be equal.

Comment: @gune Thanks. It is edited and I used Tower Property.

Comment: (+1) It's not a hint any more :)

Comment: @gune thank you for your good points.